# Add field to existing struct or variable via function without renaming or destroying the original struct

Tags: matlab

Imagine the following struct:

```
A.B1 = 1:42;
A.B2 = 'Hello World!'
```

Now I want to do some operations, but backup the existing data in a new substruct.

```
A.B1.C1 = A.B1;
A.B1.C2 = mean(A.B1.C1);
```

These two lines (as an example) I want to put into a function, so my script would look as follows:

```
A.B1 = 1:42;
A.B2 = 'Hello World!'
myfunction(A.B1)
```

and my workspace should afterwards look like:

```
A = 

    B1: [1x1 struct]
    B2: 'Hello World!'

A.B1 =

    C1: [1x42 double]
    C2: 21.5
```

But I can't manage to create that function that way, that my original struct `A` is not destroyed. Apart from that the input to my function could be `W.X.Y` and I'd like to get `W.X.Y.Z1` and `W.X.Y.Z2` afterwards. And also it could be a simple vector `A = 1:42` and should be `A.B1` and `A.B2` afterwards.

Any advices?

I could build something ugly with `fieldnames` and `assignin('base',...)` - but is this really the way to go?

---

Edit: One of the major problems is also that the function [**`inputname`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html) is not working for structs. So If I pass `A` to my function, I could then use `fieldnames` to get the names of `B1` and `B2`, but I can't find out what is the initial fieldname "`A`". If `A` would be variable `inputname(1)` in my function would return **`'A'`**. For structs the output is empty.

---

Would classes and methods be the solution? Unfortunately I'm not familiar with OOP at all...

Comment: Am I right in saying that the question boils down to: How do I figure out the number of levels/fields in a `struct` so that I can assign one additional level?

Comment: @Schorsch: for the "ugly" approach yes, additionally one needs to find out all fieldnames and write them back to workspace via `assignin`. I could do that. But I'm looking for a more elegant, generic solution.

Comment: @Schorsch and actually even that is tricky, see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I see can be something like that :

```
function [out] = myfunction(in)

    out.base = in;
    out.compute = mean(in);

end
```

And when you want to work with your function you have to provide same input/output variable like this :

```
A.B1 = 1:42;
A.B2 = 'Hello World!'
A.B1 = myfunction(A.B1);
```

---

Also possible for multiple inputs:

```
function [varargout] = myfunction(varargin)

for ii = 1:nargin

    out.base = varargin{ii};
    out.compute = mean(out.base);
    varargout{ii} = out; 

end

end
```

as long as output variables are equal in notation to their according input variables:

```
W.X.Y1 = 1:42;
W.X.Y2 = 'Hello world!';

A.B1 = 100:-1:0;
A.B2 = 'Goodbye cruel world!' 

[W.X.Y1,A.B1] = myfunction(W.X.Y1,A.B1)
```

Comment: I think you're right. I just read the edit and pretty sure, this won't works.

Comment: @Schorsch it actually would work: `W.X.Y1 = myfunction(W.X.Y1)` - but I would need it for multiple inputs, I will try that out.

Comment: For any matlab function you can have a multiple input/output. Just be sure of what you are doing and it good. The problem, that you need to be carefull and keep same structure between level. So level cannot really be a.b.c.d. But like mine e.g: `a.base.base.base.compute`

Comment: It can, as long as output and input are "equal".

Comment: Just to say : In your case maybe a function is a good idea, if you have to call it with different value. But this input/output method is more like a script method. Using same variable again and again.

Comment: I hope my edits are alright, the way you used your function was a little weird. The way I edited it it works exactly like desired.

Comment: As long is good for you and will help someone else in futur that good!